# Javascript not changing element attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the attribute "hidden" of the element to true by javascript after a timeout of 1,000 millisecond but it is not changing the attribute. Yes the timeout is working fine I've tested that, all functions are correct! Only the last part in which by using the setAttribute() function is not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="gamePanel" hidden="true">
    <div id="bb">
        <div id="map">

        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="status"> Welcome Back! </p>
    <input type="button" id="changeBio" value="Change Map" />
    <input type="button" id="saveGame" value="Save Game" />
    <div id="statusBar"> Status </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var panel = document.querySelector("#gamePanel");
panel.setAttribute("hidden","false");
```

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to change this **HTML5 attribute** in an older version of IE (or in quirks mode)?

Comment: @scunliffe No, I am using **Google Chrome**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
panel.removeAttribute("hidden");
```

Since `hidden` attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute),  (the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) defines it this way),

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
>   value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

Then, it doesn't have `true` and `false` values. It can be present (that is, `hidden` or `hidden="hidden"`), or not.

Or, even better, you can change the `hidden` property:

```
panel.hidden = false;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple solution, it works, but it messed up my CSS styling :S

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use this instead:

```
var panel = document.getElementById("gamePanel");
panel.style.display = 'block';
```

or to hide it:

```
panel.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: This is much cleaner and backwards compatible. There have been issues when using both the hidden attribute and display to determine true visibility of items (I recall a WebDriver bug specifically back in August 2013)

Comment: `hidden` attribute is semantic. `display:none` is presentational. The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#dom-hidden) explains the differences.